# Maclaurin series for $(\sin(x^3))^{1/3} $

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to find Maclaurin series for $(\sin(x^3))^{1/3} $

My attempt:

I found first derivative. $f '(x) = \frac{(x^2 \cdot  \cos x^3)}{(\sin x^3)^{2/3}}$. Hence, $f'(0)$ does not exists and there is no Maclaurin series for the function above. Nevertheless, this is incorrect answer.

By the way, I saw the same question on this forum, but the answer doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Which order do you need?

Comment: i need up to x^13

Comment: $f'(0)$ does exists.

Comment: Is it not possible to take $Lim_{x \rightarrow 0}$?

Comment: Your expression for $f'(x)$ is wrong.

Comment: You are right. Extra minus. Corrected

Comment: @ConfusedHuman It is possible to take limit, but why should i do that? It's just an ordinary function value.

Comment: @ConfusedHuman: you need to justify that $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in believing that the derivative does not exist, because you tried to obtain it by symbolic differentiation. But back to the true definition,

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sin(x^3))^{1/3}}{x}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(\sin(t))^{1/3}}{t^{1/3}}=\left(\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t)}t\right)^{1/3}=1$$ (by continuity of the cube and cubic root functions.)

---

Note that this value coincides with the limit of the symbolic expression,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\cos(x^3)}{\sin(x^3)^{2/3}}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^{2/3}}{\sin(t)^{2/3}}=1$$ though this is not a proof.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In order to find the Maclaurin series of $(\sin(x^3))^{1/3}$ at $x=0$ up to to $x^{13}$, it is better not to compute it by using the definition.
Instead, I suggest to start with the series of $\sin(x^3)$,
$$\sin(x^3)=x^3-\frac{x^9}{3!}+\frac{x^{15}}{5!}+O(x^{21}).$$
It follows that
$$(\sin(x^3))^{1/3}=\left(x^3-\frac{x^9}{3!}+\frac{x^{15}}{5!}+O(x^{21})\right)^{1/3}=
x\left(1-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^{12}}{5!}+O(x^{18})\right)^{1/3}.$$
Now use the expansion $(1+t)^{1/3}=1+\frac{t}{3}-\frac{t^2}{9}+O(t^3)$ and finish the job.

P.S. It turns out that the first derivative at $0$ exists and
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin(x^3))^{1/3}}{x}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question is just taking $r=\frac13$ and replacing $x$ by $x^3$ in the following theorem.

**Theorem.**
For $r\in\mathbb{R}$, assume that the value of the power function $\bigl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigr)^{r}$ at the point $x=0$ is $1$.

1. For $r\ge0$, the series expansion
   \begin{equation}\label{recip-sin-ser-closed-eq}\tag{SEH}
   \biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^r=1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{(-r)_k}{k!}
   \sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \frac{R\bigl(2m+j,j,-\frac{j}2\bigr)}{\binom{2m+j}{j}}\Biggr]\frac{(2x)^{2m}}{(2m)!}
   \end{equation}
   is convergent in $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where the rising factorial $(r)_k$ is defined by
   \begin{equation*}%\label{rising-Factorial}
   (r)_k=\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(r+\ell)
   =
   \begin{cases}
   r(r+1)\dotsm(r+k-1), & k\ge1\\
   1, & k=0
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation*}
   and $R\bigl(2m+j,j,-\frac{j}2\bigr)$ denotes weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind which can be explicitly computed by
   \begin{equation}\label{S(n,k,x)-satisfy-eq}
   R(n,k,r)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}(r+j)^n
   \end{equation}
   for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$.
2. For $r<0$, the series expansion \eqref{recip-sin-ser-closed-eq} is convergent in $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

For knowledge of weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind, please read the following paper [1] by Carlitz.

For the proof of the above theorem, please read the arXiv preprint [2] below.

References

1. L. Carlitz, *Weighted Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, I*, Fibonacci Quart. **18** (1980), no. 2, 147--162.
2. F. Qi, *Series expansions for any real powers of (hyperbolic) sine functions in terms of weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind*, arXiv (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.